# Virtualenv, have project directories located somewhere else, is that ok?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to use the following directory hierarchy

```
~/python/project-1
~/python/project-2
~/python/project-3
~/python/virtual-environments/environment-1 (virtual environment base)
~/python/virtual-environments/environment-2 (virtual environment base)
```

and then use it like this

```
# project-1 runs inside environment-1
source ~/python/virtual-environments/environment-1/bin/activate
cd ~/python/project-1/
python
```

.

```
# project-2 runs inside environment-2
source ~/python/virtual-environments/environment-2/bin/activate
cd ~/python/project-2/
python
```

.

```
# project-3 also runs inside environment-1
source ~/python/virtual-environments/environment-1/bin/activate
cd ~/python/project-3/
python
```

Is this allowed or could this cause some nasty problems?

I ask because it seems that

```
~/python/virtual-environments/environment-1/ (virtual environment base)
~/python/virtual-environments/environment-1/project-1
~/python/virtual-environments/environment-1/project-3 (not sure if "allowed")

~/python/virtual-environments/environment-2/ (virtual environment base)
~/python/virtual-environments/environment-2/project-2
```

is the "official" way to do it. I don't want to tie the projects so tightly to the environments and also have multiple projects use the same environment, so it's not really the inside/outside discussion, but a "completely somewhere else" one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's ok. There is even a wrapper for virtualenv called [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which does similar thing. By default it stores all virtualenvs in `~/.virtualenvs`.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about `virtualenvwrapper`. Have been using Docker for too long.